# How to display p:calendar and p:dialog with Primefaces 6.2?

Tags: primefaces, calendar, jsf-2.3

I am using Eclipse 2018-09, in addition to Apache Tomcat 9.0.14.
I also use PrimeFaces 6.2 and JSF 2.3.

The problem is that `p:calendar` is not displayed in any browser. It appears as a simple `p:inputText`. I tried in all possible ways with all the attributes I reviewed in other posts and forums.

Like `p:dialog` does not work (does not appear) and equal was tried in all forms.

Comment: Something is wrong with your project then because it means the Primefaces CSS and JS is not loading properly if you just see a TextBox instead of the Calendar.

Comment: You were right.
The problem is solved by removing the CSS styles of Bootstrap and my own styles, now what I want is to use Bootstrap without damaging PrimeFaces.

Comment: I use Bootstrap with PrimeFaces the trick is to load the Bootstrap CSS and JS AFTER PrimeFaces loads. I use Bootstrap 3.3.7.